# Can Wi-Fi router pick up signal wirelessly, similar to extender?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

Can a wifi router pick up a signal wirelessly and retransmit?

I have a cable modem that's physically connected to a `trendnet tew-810dr` router through cable. This is working fine.

I want to use a 2nd router (`Netgear R6300` router) to wirelessly pick up the signal from the 1st router, and retransmit. It would need to be wirelessly since there's no way to connect the 1st router to the 2nd router with cable.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature you are asking is provided by Bridges or Repeaters. These devices have the capabilities to work on wireless band both for downstream and upstream.

Many vendor's devices support this functionality by just changing the images (installed on the WAP).

Answer (score -1):

This kind of function is called WDS, Bridge or Reperter.
Try following this link: (How to set up Bridge mode on R6300, R6250 & R6200?)
http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20831/~/how-to-set-up-bridge-mode-on-r6300,-r6250-%26-r6200%3F?cid=wmt_netgear_organic

Comment: Thanks. By following the steps in the link, should the Netgear R6300 router pick up the wireless signal coming from the router?

Comment: Yes, it should. It's said that R6300 only supports WEP in this mode, so you may need to upgrade R6300 with third party firmware (such as DD-WRT) to support other encryptions.